# Django registration, signals and not required extra fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to know the best way to use Django registration with extra fields, and how to solve the problem with fields that I don't need to be shown, everytime I use Django registration with extra fields, I'm having problem with fields not required

## regBackend.py

```
...
profile.hobbies = form.data['hobbies']
...
```

for example hobbies field is not required, but i get error if the user don't select nothing in this field, django say "MultiValueDictKeyError"

Any idea about how to use signals and don't need to worry about the not required fields?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to get the value for a key that may or may not be present.

```
profile.hobbies = form.data.get("hobbies")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form class, you could set the optional fields to `required=False` so that if it's not selected, Django won't kick up a fuss.